# UE4: How to cast to another blueprint?

Tags: unreal-engine4, game-development, blueprint, unreal-blueprint

I have a UI widget `elevatorButton6`. When player press the button on this widget, I want to launch a bluerint `bp_elevatorButton6`, but I can't cast to it

Widget:
[image]

Here I use interface `bpi_elevatorButton`:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your GetAllActorsOfClass drag a node from Array and use GET node (with index 0). If you have only 1 BP named BP_ElevatorButton6 spawned in world you are sure that index 0 will return that object, if you have more then 1 it will return first that was found. The node from GET will go into Object node in CastTo BP_ElevatorButton6

EDIT: corrected some typos